# Codedom Resources File

Tags: vb.net, resources, codedom

I'm using codedom to build another application, but I get this error:

> 'Resources' is not a member of 'My'

Can you help me ? Thanks

Comment: The resource module is auto-generated by the IDE, it's not a compiler "feature". You need to create your own resource module.

Comment: Ok, thanks. How should I make it and use it?

Comment: I'm no expert in codedom (I've only tried it a couple of times), so you need to do some more research. Try google *"codedom + create resource class"*. Btw, here's a link which might be of interest: [Using CodeDOM to Generate VB Module](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/54e8f11c-2121-4c04-8957-04595743ef39/using-codedom-to-generate-vb-module?forum=csharplanguage)